# How to exclude a property of all entity types in EF Core configuration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

All of my models have a dynamic property called `RelatedItems`. I want to dynamically ignore these properties for all entity types.

Thus I created a base `DatabaseContext` to centralize this convention.

```
public abstract DatabaseContext : DbContext
{

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var allEntities = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes();

            foreach (var entity in allEntities)
            {
                entity.Ignore("RelatedItems");
            }
        }
}
```

But this gives me this error:

> DatabaseContext.cs(23,24): error CS1061: 'IMutableEntityType' does not contain a
> definition for 'Ignore' and no accessible extension method 'Ignore' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IMutableEntityType' could be found

How can I ignore a property on all of my models?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Get all entities and filter the ones who has the RelatedItems properties
// This filter is not required, but for safety purpose I recomend to use it
// otherwise you could end up getting some weird errors during migration scaffolding
// In my case, without it, the scaffold command alarmed about an Enum that is not even related
var allEntities = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                                            .Where(x => x.GetProperties().Count(x => x.Name == "RelatedItems") > 0);


foreach (var entity in allEntities)
{
    // Ignore property
    modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name).Ignore("RelatedItems");
}
```